# How to encode url in sharepoint using javascript

Tags: javascript, encoding

I have created an html page an used the following javascript to encode url entered in a text box.

However, it does not ecode all characters. I used a search url and tried to encode, but does not encode chars like #,=, etc.
How can I encode urls in sharepoint using javascript?

```
var res = encodeURIComponent(url)
            .replace(/!/g, '%21')
            .replace(/'/g, '%27')
            .replace(/\(/g, '%28')
            .replace(/\)/g, '%29')
            .replace(/\*/g, '%2A')
            .replace(/%20/g, '+');
```

Comment: Where are you using this encoded URL?Also you have syntax error near `encodeURIComponent(url)`.

Comment: it is working now. encoded URL is not go as it does not encode everything. 
My issue was that the changes were not properly applied to the page.

Comment: you can add the solution and close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue actually was with my file as it was not properly uploaded/saved. I had opened the html file via the explorer in Notepad++ and when I saved the file, I thought it was updated directly in SharePoint as is most of the time the case. However, in this case it was not. I pressed F12, checked my JavaScript code and I found out that the file was not updated. Then I dragged and dropped the file inside the library and everything started working fine.

A very good post about `encodeUri` and `encodeURIcomponent` can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/when-are-you-supposed-to-use-escape-instead-of-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent